# Pyramid: Set Content-Type in response to match accept header?

Tags: python, pyramid

We're using the pyramid web framework.  We use the `accept` predicate to match on the client's `Accept` header.  We use some custom headers for our json responses, like `application/vnd.whatever+json`.

What I would like is for the `Content-Type` of the response to be set equal to the `accept` predicate value.

Currently pyramid always sends back `application/json`.

How should I go about having the `Content-Type` of the response set to match the custom media type in the request `Accept` header that was negotiated?

Answer (score 3):

To set response header use:

```
request.response.content_type = 'application/download'
```

This will set Content-Type for download, but you can set whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually wanted it set according to the accept predicate.  What I've got for now is to add a wrapper function to the view with the accept predicate which sets the content_type.

Comment: This wont handle a lot of cases. For example, if you have a view that returns a Response object, the manually set content type will be ignored.

Comment: Then you add content_type parameter to that object which you return.